# Problema con la lógica de actualización de una columna en PHP al considerar múltiples registros con el mismo orden_id

Tags: php, mysql

El código PHP presenta un problema en la lógica de actualización de la columna *puntos_consumo* en una tabla, donde se espera que la resta de puntos asignados sea acumulativa hasta que se encuentre un nuevo conjunto de registros con un identificador de orden específico (*orden_id*). Sin embargo, el código reinicia incorrectamente el cálculo en cada registro, lo que conduce a resultados inexactos en la actualización de la columna *puntos_consumo*.

Para el ejemplo:
Datos en la tabla errónea o como se visualiza actualmente:

| numero_orden | id_orden | cantidad_puntos | puntos_asignados | puntos_consumo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 35 | 100 | 20 | 80 |
| 1 | 35 | 100 | 30 | 50 |
| 1 | 35 | 100 | 10 | 90 |
| 1 | 35 | 100 | 10 | 80 |

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos en la tabla como se debería visualizar:

| numero_orden | id_orden | cantidad_puntos | puntos_asignados | puntos_consumo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 35 | 100 | 20 | 80 |
| 1 | 35 | 100 | 30 | 50 |
| 1 | 35 | 100 | 10 | 40 |
| 1 | 35 | 100 | 10 | 30 |

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este el el código que tengo actualmente:

```
// Consulta para obtener los registros en tabla cantidad_puntos
$sql = "SELECT ct.id_cant_puntos, ct.numero_orden, os.id AS orden_id, os.cantidad_puntos, ct.puntos_asignados, ct.puntos_consumo, ct.id_orden 
        FROM cantidad_puntos ct
        JOIN ordenes_servicios os ON ct.numero_orden = os.numero_orden
        WHERE ct.id_orden = os.id
        ORDER BY ct.id_cant_puntos";

// Prepara la consulta principal
$stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

// Prepara la consulta de actualización fuera del bucle
$updateStmt = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE cantidad_puntos SET puntos_consumo = :puntos_consumo WHERE id_cant_puntos = :id_cant_puntos");

// Inicializa variables
$puntos_consumo_anterior = 0;
$numero_orden_anterior = null;
$orden_id_anterior = null;

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // Verifica si el número de orden o el id de orden cambian
    if ($row["numero_orden"] !== $numero_orden_anterior || $row["orden_id"] !== $orden_id_anterior) {
        // Si cambian, reinicia los puntos_consumo solo si es el primer registro de un nuevo orden
        if ($numero_orden_anterior !== null) {
            // Realiza la consulta de actualización antes de reiniciar los puntos_consumo
            $updateStmt->execute(['puntos_consumo' => $puntos_consumo_anterior, 'id_cant_puntos' => $row_anterior["id_cant_puntos"]]);
        }
        // Reinicia los puntos_consumo solo si es el primer registro de un nuevo orden
        $puntos_consumo_anterior = $row["cantidad_puntos"];
    }

    // Realiza la operación de resta
    $puntos_consumo_anterior -= $row["puntos_asignados"];

    // Almacena los valores actuales para la siguiente iteración
    $numero_orden_anterior = $row["numero_orden"];
    $orden_id_anterior = $row["orden_id"];
    $row_anterior = $row; // Almacena el estado actual para la próxima iteración

}

// Ejecuta la última consulta de actualización fuera del bucle
if ($numero_orden_anterior !== null) {
    $updateStmt->execute(['puntos_consumo' => $puntos_consumo_anterior, 'id_cant_puntos' => $row_anterior["id_cant_puntos"]]);
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! a esa tabla le falta una fecha o un orden que la ordene.. la columna que usas como orden, no es valida, ese query puede ordenarse como quiere

Comment: Me pregunto por qué no sumas en la misma consulta usando `SUM()` y `GROUP BY id_orden`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema en tu lógica actual se debe a que estás reiniciando los `puntos_consumo` cada vez que encuentras un nuevo `orden_id` o `numero_orden`, pero realmente lo que necesitas es llevar un seguimiento acumulativo de los `puntos_consumo` para cada `orden_id`. Es decir, necesitas restar los `puntos_asignados` del total de `cantidad_puntos` para cada registro asociado con el mismo `orden_id`, y actualizar este valor en la base de datos.

Considera lo siguiente:

1. En lugar de reiniciar los puntos_consumo para cada fila, mantén un
   registro de los puntos consumidos por cada orden_id.
2. Resta los puntos_asignados de los puntos consumidos acumulados para
   cada orden_id.
3. Actualiza los puntos_consumo en la base de datos para cada fila,
   usando los puntos consumidos acumulados.

```
    // Consulta para obtener los registros en tabla cantidad_puntos
    $sql = "SELECT ct.id_cant_puntos, ct.numero_orden, os.id AS orden_id, os.cantidad_puntos, ct.puntos_asignados, ct.puntos_consumo, ct.id_orden 
            FROM cantidad_puntos ct
            JOIN ordenes_servicios os ON ct.numero_orden = os.numero_orden
            WHERE ct.id_orden = os.id
            ORDER BY ct.id_cant_puntos";
    
    $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    $updateStmt = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE cantidad_puntos SET puntos_consumo = :puntos_consumo WHERE id_cant_puntos = :id_cant_puntos");
    
    $puntos_consumo_por_orden = [];
    
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $orden_id = $row["orden_id"];

    
        // Inicializa los puntos_consumo para este orden_id si es necesario
        if (!isset($puntos_consumo_por_orden[$orden_id])) {
            $puntos_consumo_por_orden[$orden_id] = $row["cantidad_puntos"];
        }
    
        // Resta los puntos_asignados del total acumulado
        $puntos_consumo_por_orden[$orden_id] -= $row["puntos_asignados"];
    
        // Actualiza la base de datos
        $updateStmt->execute([
            'puntos_consumo' => $puntos_consumo_por_orden[$orden_id],
            'id_cant_puntos' => $row["id_cant_puntos"]
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: si haces esto: if (!isset($puntos_consumo_por_orden[$orden_id])) {
            $puntos_consumo_por_orden[$orden_id] = $row["cantidad_puntos"];
        } no estas reiniciando los puntos por cada fila??? si tenes varias filas, con que valor va a quedar???

Comment: @gbianchi, mil gracias por tu ayuda, quedo muy bien, también muchas gracias por la explicación. Funciona perfecto.

Comment: @JohanPeña yo no te ayude en nada, deje un comentario a quien hizo la respuesta, porque no estoy seguro que funcione al 100%.. sin embargo, si funciono y la respuesta te sirvio, recuerda acaptarla...

Comment: muchas gracias a todos aquellos que contribuyeron y brindaron su ayuda. ¡Mil gracias! Su apoyo fue invaluable y me permitió superar el desafío que estaba enfrentando. Aprecio enormemente la generosidad de la comunidad. ¡Gracias de nuevo